# My Realtek WIFI is malfunctioning

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek

[Details of my wifi card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZuZn.png)

The problem is that the WIFI connects after starting Ubuntu but after 2-3 minutes, it just disconnects then I can't even connect to any other network because they don't show.

My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

It is a really frustrating problem that I have had for a while. Previously, I was on dual boot, so I thought that it must be because of it. After cleaning my whole HDD and having only one 1 OS - Ubuntu, the problem is still there.

I have tried the arping method, where you ping 198.168.1.1 every 2-3 minutes, but that didn't help me much either.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438133/edit) your question and explain what your problem is.  Also, add what version of Ubuntu you are running as well as any more hardware details that you can add.  The more details you add the better we might be able to help.

Comment: @Terrance Added

Comment: Maybe try reloading the driver for that card.  `sudo apt install --reinstall rtl8821ce-dkms`

Comment: @Terrance It worked but I don't know if it'll stay like this for a long tiime. Will update.

Comment: @Terranc started bugging again :(